# Have I correctly transformed these equations into a matrix of type $Ax = b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Some Background: I'm trying to implement the algorithm from [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6163372/) paper, and I'm having trouble with equation (15) and (16).

Given is the following minimizing problem for the variables $m,n,p,q,k$.

$H = arg \quad min_{m,n,p,q,k} \sum\limits_{i \in U}(mI_ix_i^2 + nI_iy_i^2 + pl_ix_i + qI_iy_i + kI_i + I_i\ln(I_i))^2$
$H = arg \quad min_{m,n,p,q,k} \sum\limits_{i \in U}h_i^2$

The paper provides the partial derivatives

$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\partial H}{\partial m} =  \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_ix_i^2h_i = 0 \\
 \frac{\partial H}{\partial n} =  \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_iy_i^2h_i = 0 \\
 \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} =  \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_ix_ih_i = 0 \\
 \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} =  \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_iy_ih_i = 0 \\
 \frac{\partial H}{\partial k} =  \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_ih_i = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$

and states that this can be solved for the optimal parameters $\overline{m},\overline{n},\overline{p},\overline{q},\overline{k}$.

Following is my transformation of these 5 equations into a matrix of the form $Ax = b$:

$\begin{cases}
 \sum\limits_{i \in U}(m2I_i^2x_i^4 + n2I_i^2x_i^2y_i^2 +  p2I_i^2x_i^3 + q2I_i^2x_i^2y_i + k2I_i^2x_i^2 + 2I_i^2x_i^2\ln(I_i)= 0) \\
 \sum\limits_{i \in U}(m2I_i^2x_i^2y_i^2 + n2I_i^2y_i^4 +  p2I_i^2x_iy_i^2 + q2I_i^2y_i^3 + k2I_i^2y_i^2 + 2I_i^2y_i^2\ln(I_i)= 0) \\
 \sum\limits_{i \in U}(m2I_i^2x_i^3 + n2I_i^2x_iy_i^2 +  p2I_i^2x_i^2 + q2I_i^2x_iy_i + k2I_i^2x_i + 2I_i^2x_i\ln(I_i)= 0) \\
 \sum\limits_{i \in U}(m2I_i^2x_i^2y_i + n2I_i^2y_i^3 +  p2I_i^2x_iy_i + q2I_i^2y_i^2 + k2I_i^2y_i + 2I_i^2y_i\ln(I_i)= 0) \\
 \sum\limits_{i \in U}(m2I_i^2x_i^2 + n2I_i^2y_i^2 +  p2I_i^2x_i + q2I_i^2y_i + k2I_i^2 + 2I_i^2\ln(I_i)= 0) \\
\end{cases}
$

Pull in sums and subtract the term without a variable:

$
\begin{cases}
 m\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^4 + n\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i^2 +  p\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^3 + q\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i + k\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2 = - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2\ln(I_i) \\
 m\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i^2 + n\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^4 +  p\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i^2 + q\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^3 + k\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2 = - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2\ln(I_i) \\
 m\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^3 + n\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i^2 +  p\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2 + q\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i + k\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i = - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i\ln(I_i) \\
 m\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i + n\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^3 +  p\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i + q\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2 + k\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i = - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i\ln(I_i) \\
 m\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2 + n\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2 +  p\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i + q\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i + k\sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2 = - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2\ln(I_i) \\
\end{cases}
$

This results in

$A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^4 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2\\
    \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^4 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2 \\
    \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i \\
    \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2y_i & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_iy_i & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i\\
    \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i & \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

$x =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    m\\
    n\\
    p\\
    q\\
    k\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

$b =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i^2\ln(I_i)\\
    - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i^2\ln(I_i)\\
    - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2x_i\ln(I_i)\\
    - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2y_i\ln(I_i)\\
    - \sum\limits_{i \in U}2I_i^2\ln(I_i)\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

Is this correct? I'm asking because code I've written based on this is giving me questionable results and I suspect I have done something wrong.

Comment: This is entirely correct, what "questionalble" results do you get?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The paper suggests that using 5 pixels is enough for a good initial guess. When I did that my results where either way off or NaN. I've since  tried expanding to more pixels, and the results seem to become stable(and correct). I'll probably make this an answer once I've done some more testing.

Comment: This is a general phenomonon in least square approximations, e.g. for a third degree polynomial regression one needs at least four points to produce a reasonable result.